# Comma or no comma after Mr. Thomas & do I need the word “message.”

Tags: grammar, nouns, commas, pronouns, greetings

Dr. Thomas I saw Dr. Smith and relied your hello message to him.

Comment: Yes, it is relayed thanks for the correction, do I need a comma after Dr. Thomas and do I need to include the word “message”?

Comment: I would be happier with the comma. As for the message I think it would depend on whether it contained more than "Hello".

Comment: It is only “hello.”

Comment: Here are the options

Comment: relayed your hello, relayed your hello message, or relayed your message of hello

Comment: What word would be best? relayed or conveyed

Comment: Relayed or conveyed - either is OK, but rather formal. I would be more likely to say "passed on".

Comment: Dr. Thomas, I saw Dr. Smith today and I told him you say "hello."  What if past tense; I saw Dr. Smith last week and I told him you SAID or SAY hello.

Comment: When you name the person being spoken to in a  sentence, it is standard form to set off the person's name with a comma (or two, if injected in the middle of the sentence).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say: Dr. Thomas, I saw Dr. Smith today and I relayed your "hello" to him. Or, even better, you could say: Dr. Thomas, I saw Dr. Smith today and I told him you say "hello."

Comment: Thanks, but if it’s in past tense: I saw Dr. Smith last week and I told him you SAID hello.